# location of python application entry point files in the repository

Tags: python, package, repository, structure, entry-point

I am developing a python application, from my search usually the repository structure is something similar to this:

```
my_application/
│
├── my_application/ # sometimes also called src/
├── test/
├── docs/
├── LICENSE
├── requirements.txt
└── .gitignore
```

My question is where do [`entry_points`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point) (the files that I use to start running my application code) go?

---

I may have several entry points depending on the way I run my app, for an `AWS-lambda` there needs to be a entry point file that contains a `handler_*` function, `GCP-Function` requires something else etc..

Comment: I think you are talking about packaging the aplication for install. See [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html)

Comment: @progmatico This is a pythonic entry point and it's just one other entry point, I would use it if I want to run my application like this `python -m application`. 
however some run time environment's require different application entry points.